# Getting four corners of a rotated element using getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, rotation, angle

`getBoundingClientRect()` only returns one corner i.e. ( upper left ), how to calculate other three corners given the upper left corner if the element is rotated by css transform.

Comment: *"getBoundingClientRect() only returns one corner i.e., upper left"*... no, it returns all 4 corners.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado isn't x and y returned by getBoundingClientRect()  upper left co-ordinates ?

Comment: Yes, but you have `bottom`, `height`, `left`, `right`, `top` and `width` as well.

Comment: I got my answer ty

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` won't give you the exact corners of a rotated element, but instead, it'll give you the corners and dimensions of the "bounding rect". As in, even if you rotated the element, imagine a non-rotated rectangle perfectly wrapping your now rotated element. This rectangle is what you get from `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: @JayantBhawal the wrapping non-rotated rectangle's top is one corner of rotated element, its left is other corner, same goes with bottom and right. But you are not sure which corner is that e.g the top of wrapping element could be any corner of rotated element i.e upper left or upper right or bottom left or bottom right.

Comment: Do you have the 4 original corners coordinates? In the non-rotated rectangle?